# How to break up layers when georeferencing in QGIS when adding to project

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm trying to take an Illustrator file that has multiple layers, and get it into QGIS to georeference each layer. I've been able to get the entire polygon in as one layer, but I can't figure out how to get each layer in separately after georeferencing.

The Illustrator file I created has 6 layers. Each layer represents an area on a map.

I exported the Illustrator file to .dxf file format. I took this file and added it as a Vector in the QGIS Georeferencer.

I added control points based on the map coordinates. I'm using Linear referencing in the settings.

The input looks like this: [image: Screnshot]

And the polygon gets added as this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

At what step would I 'break' the big polygon into the six original layers? I'm trying to get six different shapes geocoded.

Comment: Did you mix up "layers" with "features"? Currently you vector data is of line-geometry-type.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the workaround. Maybe it will help someone else. In Illustrator each Layer/shape needs to be exported by itself to a .dxf. What is also important, is there can be no other layers, even hidden layers. I tried hiding all five other layers, and the dxf still contained all six.

Then using Georeference in QGIS, add the Vector layer, and map the points of the first shape.

It's not as bad as it sounds if you don't have too many layers. I exported each layer to its own .dxf in Illustrator.

Then, in Georeference, after adding/replacing each layer, load up the first set of map points. It will preserve the geo coding of the new shape. This way it's not necessary to map every shape, just the first one.